# Crystal reports Count group by

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new to Crystal reports and I am working on fixing an existing report. 
I am having an issue with a simple function, I am attempting to count the number of patients for each provider. I am connecting to EPIC Clarity database, if that helps. When I use the following, I am expecting to get a count of the patients (based on the number of `PAT_ID, A unique field` ) , grouped by the `PROV_ID (also a unique field)  count({PATIENT.PAT_ID},{CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID})`

This results in the error: There must be a group that matches this field.

I am not sure what this error is trying to tell me. I have never used crystal reports before and I am not sure where to begin.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you do not have a group in your report, you should add a group from the  "reports" menu.  If you already have groups, then the "PROV_ID" needs to be "Goup 1".  You should be able to drag aggregates columns from the Fields Explorer - also, Crystal Version?

Comment: I have no clue what Crystal version.
Also how can I tell if I have a group in the report already.  
and what does {%xyz} mean?  I am not sure what the {% is for.

Comment: There is an "About" menu SOMEWHERE in the software.  find out what version.  it matters.  or look at the properties of the executable.  it appears that you may need some education before you start banging around in Crystal.  its sort've tricky and you can cause irreparable damage to a report. Check out this series on youtube (not my work, just found on Google): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM_89QmQXK8

Comment: if you need a Crystal Reports consultant email info@lightspeedsolutions.com

Comment: If you are able, please give screen shot